# Where are the page length settings after a page has been created

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint site that already has a doc lib with docs in it. Doc are opened in one note. After opening there are parts of the page that are overlayed. I move the frame and am able to get the overlayed information. Where are the page lengths set to not have information overlayed?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the issue.